# Problems with html5 canvas, inside a native WebView in react native

Tags: android, react-native, canvas, webview, wkwebview

After set width > 640 and height > 100, nothing is drawn in canvas, this problem occurs  when the web page is rendered  inside a native web view.

```
//works fine
...
canvas.width  = 640;
canvas.height = 100;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
...

//don't  works
...
canvas.width  = 1024;
canvas.height = 768;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, changing the  dimensions  when the DOM has been loaded, like in code below

```
window.onload  =  function()  {
canvas.width  = 1024;
canvas.height = 768;

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 300);
};
img.src = "./same_image.jpg";
// ...
};
```

but, when I try draw a SVG Image, not works.

```
window.onload  =  function()  {
canvas.width  = 1024;
canvas.height = 768;

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 300);
};
img.src = "./same_image.svg";
// ...
};
```